# how to use for loop continuously image slider?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a image slider in android that scrolls automatically after every 2000s. I have written the code ,but i don't know to loop the code automatically after every 2000s. Now  I have 2 static images to test the slider scroll ,it just scrolls to the second image and stops.but it is not looping continuosly to 1st one when it reaches the last image.

Here is my code(i want to loop this code continuously)

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    mRecyclerViewTwo.smoothScrollToPosition(1);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if (2 <= mPostad.size()) {
          mRecyclerViewTwo.smoothScrollToPosition(2);
        } else {
          mRecyclerViewTwo.smoothScrollToPosition(1);
        }
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Please help.
Any help is appreciatable.

Comment: When you have performed the inner most scroll, you need to re-schedule the outer runnable.

Comment: PPatision's answer will work. Or you can use View pager with Auto scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(this::codeToExecute, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

private void codeToExecute() {
    if (2 <= mPostad.size()) {
        mRecyclerViewTwo.smoothScrollToPosition(2);
    } else {
        mRecyclerViewTwo.smoothScrollToPosition(1);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: That said, from reading your question you may well find a pre-existing widget that does this job for you. Maybe a `ViewFlipper`?